# Is it possible to monitor / retrieve variable values in use on NodeJS server?

Tags: node.js, monitoring

What tools can you use to monitor or access data in use on a Node server? A comparison would be using the Javascript Console for a browser and being able to console.log a variable value to the console or execute methods. Is there something similar you can do with a NodeJS server?

Edit: An example; if I deployed my server to an AWS ec2 instance could someone managing the datacenter theoretially access my server and monitor/view the data in use? If so, how?

Comment: `node inspector` is a debugger that let's you debug your server-side js using the Chrome developer tools. You can step through code, watch expressions, set breakpoints, and everything through the Chrome developer tools.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you in debugging
 http://techblog.netflix.com/2015/12/debugging-nodejs-in-production.html